# Stripe different possible value of charge->status

Tags: php, stripe-payments

The token is generated with a payment by card.

What are the different values possible of $charge->status knowing that any failure will break the code thanks to the Exception.

```
    try {
        if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
            throw new Exception('The Stripe Token was not generated correctly');

        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => 1000,
            "currency" => "eur",
            "description" => "Basket items",
            "source" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
        ));


    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $error = $e->getMessage();

        show__errorPayment($error);

        exit;

    }

if($charge->status == 'succeeded') {
  // Payment done, inserting in db, making PDF invoice...etc...
}
```

I didn't find in the documentation if the status can be for example "pending". Not failed but pending...

If so, I would have to had it in my code:

```
if($charge->status == 'succeeded') {
  // Payment done, inserting in db, making PDF invoice...etc...
} else if($charge->status == 'pending') {
  //To do...
}
```

Comment: now what is the question?

Comment: @dean Can `$charge->status` be "pending"?

Comment: Pending status is only applicable to things like `ACH` (bank transfer) where there are several days where you do not know if the charge has succeeded or not. With cards, that's instant. It has either succeeded or Stripe will throw an exception.